# How to pass a relative path (relative to main bundle) to iOS app as "argument passed on launch" in Schemes?

Tags: ios, xcode, arguments, bundle, relative-path

I try to pass a relative path, e.g., `subFolder/file`, as an argument to my app. The subFolder is placed in Copy Bundle Resources and I made sure that the folder is under myApp.app/Contents/.
I added an argument in my Scheme > Run > Arguments > Arguments Passed On Launch, as
`subFolder/file`.

However, when running the app, the debugger output says:

```
/var/mobile/applications/feae1664-6f16-4b96-8b8d-05b4531fe6da/myApp.app/myappbin: cannot open subFolder/file: No such file or directory
```

`myappbin` is the executable of the app bundle.

How should I specify a relative path like this?

**EDIT**

the thing is my app really needs to use that path as a runtime variable, for testing purposes. I do know how to refer to the bundled folders/files in mainBundle in ObjC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass in the path as an argument. You just need to use the NSBundle methods to return the path.

Have a look at

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResouce: ofType:];
```

And also the documentation for NSBundle,
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Well, the thing is my app really needs to use that path as a runtime variable, for testing purposes. I do know how to refer to them in mainBundle in ObjC. Is it that the sandbox mechanism forbids that we pass in the relative path?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? The relative path will be in relation to the bundle so you can use [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] and append your relative path to that.

Comment: Well, my app uses a lua script as input to do something. I guess I can pass the filename alone as the arg and compose the full path using your tip in ObjC then. Thanks.